# How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, ihaskell

I would like to apply a few simple changes to the appearance of my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebooks, such as:

```
    rendered_html :link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried many of the solutions I've found by searching, e.g., placing CSS in:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/static/css/custom.css
```

but none have any effect, and I suspect that, given the recent changes to the Notebook architecture, the method for accomplishing this has changed and that the instructions I'm finding are out of date.

How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?

---

OS X 10.10.4; Xcode 6.4; CLT: 6.4.0.0.1; Clang: 6.1; Python Python 2.7.10 (Homebrew); IHaskell 0.6.4.1, IPython 3.0.0 (answers for 4.0.0 and Jupiter 4.0 also appreciated, as I will upgrade soon).

Comment: profiles were removed with IPython/Jupyter version 4.0, I have not yet discovered how to edit the CSS in 4.0

Comment: In 4.0, it's been moved to ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css

Comment: @RandyC: I have no such directory or file, and the [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158550/656912) below works.

Comment: Since [`5.5.0`](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/295#issuecomment-405033501) Conda users can find it in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.css` (depending on the version of Python they're on).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the path to your `custom.css` should be:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css
```

`custom` folder instead of `css` folder.

Comment: Sure enough. I have no idea where `.../css/custom.css` came from. Confusingly though,  `.../custom/custom.css` says "Placeholder for custom user CSS mainly to be overridden in profile/static/custom/custom.css. This will always be an empty file in IPython".

Comment: I've put the file in that `/custom` folder, but no effect. Did it help in your case, @raxacoricofallapatorius? I am using Jupiter

Comment: I have windows 7 64-bit, but I am not sure how to check the jupyter/iPython version

Comment: In a Jupyter/IPython notebook write: `import jupyter_core;jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_config_dir() + '\\custom'` to get the path to the custom folder

Comment: Found, just different profile indeed, thanks. Though the line you provided did not help: jupyter_core was not found among the packages.

Comment: Great. My line above works with latests versions of jupyter... Lately it is a little mess to understand all the internal changes in the notebook :-(

Comment: @kikocorreoso: This has no effect for me in the current versions of IPython and Jupyter.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius are you using conda or anaconda or a conda-env?

Comment: @kikocorreoso: No: just Python and pip. Everything related to Jupyter/IPython was installed with the same Python/pip.

Comment: I had to restart jupyter for the changes to take effect. My file is in `~/.jupyter/custom/`. Make sure to test your changes in dev tools first, so you know your `CSS` is valid.

Answer (score 97):

To add custom CSS to a particular notebook you can use [`HTML`](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=html#IPython.display.HTML). Add and execute a regular Python code cell with the following content:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
</style>
""")
```

Alternatively (thanks @abalter) use the `%%html` cell magic:

```
%%html
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is really about doing this in configuration, not code.

Comment: FWIW, now the easier way to do it is by just using the html cell magic `%%html`

Comment: This just seems to display the text of the CSS as output but not apply it to the notebook. What am I missing?

Comment: @davidrpugh both options still work for me. Note the `<style></style>` is required.

Comment: This works great for me. Different  notebook topics can be a custom theme if you wish.

Comment: What if you aren't using a python kernel?

Comment: No idea. I've not use non-Python kernels. Maybe the `%%html` cell magic works anyway?

Comment: The `%%html` magic doesn't work with the `xeus-cling` kernel. I think the kernel has to implement each magic (the `xeus-cling` documentation suggests that might be the case).

Answer (score 71):

Starting Jupyter / IPython 4.1, the custom folder location has changed to `~/.jupyter/custom/`. So place your `custom.css` and `custom.js` like this:

```
~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css
~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js
```

Works for me that way. Credits goes to [Liang2](https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2016/01/jupyter-notebook-theme/)

---

**Edit:**

If you are missing `~/.jupyter` folder, you can use `jupyter notebook --generate-config` command to generate the folder.

Comment: This has no effect for me. Is this up to date?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it on clean Ubuntu 14.04 with latest version from pip. I've only edited the answer because you can miss `~/.jupyter` folder after fresh Jupyter install.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you might need a `!important` on your CSS rule.

Comment: Is there any way to use `custom.css` the same folder as the jupyter notebook?

Comment: note that you need to restart jupyter for the changes to take effect

Comment: I'm using this configuration and it's working fine for Jupyter 4.4.0.

Comment: @ostrokach It would be really nice if there was a way to do this; I've been looking for one but haven't found anything so far...

Comment: @ostrokach Oh wait, there is! See Diego Ortiz's answer below! :)

Answer (score 20):

Here is what I did.

From https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR I found out that you can change the config directory by setting the **JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR** env var, then I run jupyter like:

```
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=./jupyter/ jupyter notebook
```

My jupyter dir in current dir has the following structure:

```
jupyter/
- custom/
  - custom.css
  - custom.js
```

Comment: This answer should be way higher! It took me hours to find how to define a per-project config!

Comment: updated url: https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR

Answer (score 9):

**As of 2021**, Jupyter 4.7, Ipython 7, the following location worked for me:

```
/home/$USER/.jupyter/custom/custom.css
```

Old answer:

According to Jupyter documentation `custom.css` should be put into the `default_profile/static/custom` folders.

You will find the location of your default profile by running in a Jupyter notebook cell:

```
import jupyter_core
jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_config_dir()
```

Which gave me:

```
'/home/sergey/.jupyter'
```

Afterwards, in `.jupyter` folder create directory structure like:

```
static
└── custom
    └── custom.css
```

As you see the desired structure is `~/.jupyter/static/custom/custom.css`

This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 and latest Jupyter (October 2018)

Answer (score 7):

Per the suggested documentation, I downloaded Anaconda3 first and from within Anaconda Navigator - Jupyter 5.0 Notebook is one of several pre-built options. 
I found my CSS file at this location.

`C:\Users\YourUsername\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css`

Answer (score 6):

I found a nice solution here:
https://martinapugliese.github.io/jupyter-customise/

I needed to add this  however:

```html
<style>..</style>
```

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def _set_css_style(css_file_path):
   """
   Read the custom CSS file and load it into Jupyter.
   Pass the file path to the CSS file.
   """

   styles = open(css_file_path, "r").read()
   s = '<style>%s</style>' % styles     
   return HTML(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

For **base conda environment** I found it here:
~/Programs/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/custom

For **custom conda environment** I found it here:
~/Programs/Anaconda3/envs/[environment name]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/custom

Works under Ubuntu 18.04, conda 4.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Jupyter on Google Cloud Platform using Tensorflow Docker image and it was located at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/static/custom/`. In Any case, you can find it by searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't add comment due to reputation so I'll post as an answer.

The `/custom/custom.css` stopped working for me when I generated a config file, but if anyone stumbles to this problem too, the solution is to uncomment the line `c.NotebookApp.extra_static_paths = []` in the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file and add "./custom/" - or whatever path you chose for your custom css - inside the brackets.

P.S.: OS is Linux Manjaro 5.12 and Jupyter Notebook version is 6.3.0.

Comment: Where exactly is the `.py` located?

Comment: @amzon-ex on linux it's usually on the /home/.jupyter folder (a hidden folder, so you have to press `Ctrl+h` to see it). On Windows I'm not sure but it's probably on C:\Users\username\.jupyter. If you don't have a config file yet you can create with the command `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows

```
C:\Users\<username>\.jupyter\custom\custom.css
```

the above will override the default location: in `site-packages` https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/295

Answer (score 0):

If you install it via PIP and not Anaconda, then it's going to be in this folder 
`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom` 
From here you can find the `custom.css` file and edit that to get the changes reflected. You will also have the `custom.js` file present there as well.

Comment: Actually `%APPDATA%\Python\Python39\site-packages\notebook\static\custom`.

Answer (score -1):

**Ubunutu 18.04**

Folder
~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/static/custom

venv is the virtual environment name so the location is relative to your environment's location.

Here, there is a placeholder file, 'custom.css'.
Override it with your own css.

**Any machine with Conda installation**

C:\Users******.conda\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom

Use the path relative to .conda. My environment name is py37

Place your custom css in the custom.css file here.

Reload jupyter notebook.