# How to print the full NumPy array without wrapping (in Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

This question is different from this one: [How to print the full NumPy array, without truncation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array-without-truncation)

In that question, the user wanted to know how to print the full array without *truncation.* I can print the array without truncation just fine. **My problem is that only a small portion of the screen width is used. When trying to inspect large adjacency matrices, it's impossible to inspect them when the rows unnecessarily wrap.**

I'm asking this question here because it always takes me hours to find the solution, and I want to disambiguate it from that answer post above.

For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
graph = nx.gnm_random_graph(20, 20, 1)
nx.to_numpy_matrix(graph)
```

This output displays as:

[image: Jupyter Notebook Numpy - Array Wrapping]

Comment: np.set_printoptions( linewidth=100) or whatever

Comment: Write your own good old `print_as_you_like_to_see_it()` function maybe?

Comment: Answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59058418/3857460.

Answer (score 17):

Just gonna post NaN's comment as the answer:

Use `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=n)` where `n` has to do with the number of characters (not array elements) per line. So in your case `n=100` should do the trick.