# Change size of body text in Jupyter notebook

Tags: css, fonts, jupyter-notebook, font-size

I'd like to increase the size of all body text (I don't know the right term, but text that is not in a special markdown category) in a dozen Jupyter notebooks. The notebooks are all stored in one repo, so they can share a css file. But I've no expertise in css.

The directory containing these notebooks has this `custom.css` file

```
h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}

#TOC, #book-cover {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#TOC {
    font-size: 130%;
}

#main_content_wrap p, #main_content_wrap ol {
    text-align: justify;
}

#main_content_wrap ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#main_content_wrap ul li a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#image-cc {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

but I do not know if it is being used. The system (a Docker container) contains a `.jupyter` directory, but it contains no css files.

Ideally, I'd like a reference to a clear, fairly simple manual on using css for Jupyter notebooks. I'm aware of this good [CSS reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), but it does not consider Jupyter notebooks. ("Give a man a fish ..., teach a man to fish ...")

Thanks, Arthur

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook. See if you can find a path like `static/custom/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the body tag font size, it will change the text everywhere. This includes relative sized css like your `#TOC` id which is based in `%` and also will impact any relative size values like `em`.

```
body { font-size: 20px; }
```