# What is the official name of this title bar from matplotlib and how do I hide it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib, and I don't know what the name of the title bar arrowed in following image is.

[image: Title bar]

I googled and dug from matplotlib official documentation, but I didn't get a clue.

What is the official name of this title bar from matplotlib, and how do I to hide it?

I don't want to remove the interactivity; I just want to hide the bar, because when I interact with the plot, the title bar flex/Stretch rapidly, which is so boring and distracting

Comment: You seem to have `%matplotlib notebook` somewhere in your Jupyter Notebook. As the answer below suggests, use `%matplotlib inline` instead

Comment: @Bazingaa I said 'I don't want to remove the interactivity'

Comment: My bad. I need a coffee perhaps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title bar of the figure may be called `dialog-titlebar` judging from its name in the layout. It is a `<div>` element of the output's DOM tree. To hide such elements, they may be given the `display: none;` property via CSS. Somewhere in your notebook you may state

```
%%html
<style>
div.ui-dialog-titlebar {display: none;}
</style>
```

[image]

See [How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook) for how to apply this potentially to any notebook by default.

An alternative is to not use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend, but `%matplotlib widget` instead. This is part of [jupyter-matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) and currently needs to be installed separately as shown in the link. It'll by default have no titlebar while still providing full interactivity. There is a looong term plan to have it replace the `%matplotlib notebook` backend - but "looong" has many "o"s here.

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to as "title bar", is actually part of the [notebook backend](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) - essentially the code that translates what you write in python to something that can be visualised as a figure. The `notebook` backend is made to be interactive within Jupyter notebooks, and as such has that bar, plus buttons you can use to pan, zoom, etc. When you save the figure via `plt.savefig()` or by clicking the `save` button, the bar will not appear.

If you want to get rid of the interactivity all together, try using the `%matplotlib inline` magic instead - that will select the `inline` backend, and remove the interactivity.