# How to remove the window title of a matplotlib figure when using the widget backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I use the widget backend to embed an interactive matplotlib figure in an `ipywidgets.GridBox`.
The window title takes up too much space and I want to remove it.
With `plt.figure(' ')` it becomes invisible but even with `fig.tight_layout()` the space is still reserved and takes up useless space in my layout.
Below is a minimal example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib widget
plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure('remove the title')
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
fig.tight_layout()
display(fig.canvas)
```

I found a few examples [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) but no complete list of backend specific options. 
In this related post a solution for the notebook backend is given. [what is the official name of this title bar from matplotlib, how to hide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620922/what-is-the-official-name-of-this-title-bar-from-matplotlib-how-to-hide-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is a little late but maybe someone else is interested, too. For this special backend the title can be made invisible by

```
%%html
<style>
div.jupyter-widgets.widget-label {display: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to solve it in the meantime so it is still useful

Comment: I am very pleased about that. If this solves your problem don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I realized that this not only removes the title but also the x and y coordinates of the cursor which are shown below the figure. is there a way to keep them?