# control of toolbar and titlebar using jupyter + matplotlib + imshow

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, imshow

I'm looking for a bit of finer control over the display of `imshow` in a Jupyter notebook.

Unlike `%matplotlib inline` (default) the magic command `%matplotlib notebook` causes `imshow` to add a toolbar below the figure, and this thing

[image: matplotlib imshow titlebar]

above the figure which I'm going to call the titlebar (it's a `<div>` element called `dialog-titlebar`).

Within one notebook I want to specifically control titlebar, toolbar and interactive pixel display on an `imshow` by `imshow` basis.  I can use `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` to turn all these things on or off, but I want something more nuanced (for teaching purposes I want to remove everything that's distracting or not relevant to the discussion).

Questions:

1. Is there a way to turn off the figure toolbar programatically?  If yes, does that include the pixel value display, or are they separately controllable?  Is it possible to remove buttons, for `imshow` many of them are not relevant.
2. Is there a way to turn off the interactive pixel display?  I know I can use `format_coord` but that just stops the callback from displaying stuff, I want to turn off the call-back machinery for performance reasons.

Comment: I don't understand how `if`, "pixel value" and `format_coord` are related. Can you check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620922/what-is-the-official-name-of-this-title-bar-from-matplotlib-how-to-hide-it/52622312) answers you rproblem, or at least it adapt it accordingly?

Comment: that question only provides static options to control these elements, magic commands or CSS code.  I want programmatic control.

Comment: I don't think I grasp what exactly needs to be programmatically controlled (on/off is a binary thing, so it's static, right?). But if the question can be updated to make that clearer, I can have another look.

Comment: question is updated and hopefully clarified