# How to make Tufte-style sidenotes in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, markdown, tufte

I'm new to Jupyter notebooks, and also new to markdown. It seems like a very powerful tool for sharing blended python code and text. One thing I'd like to be able to do is to use Tufte-style formatting for sidenotes using the markdown syntax.

something like https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/tufte-handouts.html

Perhaps this functionality is easier than it appears, 
since the above link appears to be using markdown, so I suspect it's possible. However I can't seem to figure out how to approach this problem.

I read from: [How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook)

```
%%html
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
</style>
```

This shows potential. I have a *Very* small amount of background in CSS.

However, due to my noobness, I can't figure out how to add custom functionality like this to a Jupyter notebook. Any help would be appreciated.