# How to remove accidental CSS from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

Jupyter lets you change the CSS of an individual notebook within the notebook itself as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570738/6575728):

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
</style>
""")
```

However Jupyter makes these changes persist somehow and I can't figure out how to get rid of them short of creating a new notebook: clearing the browser cache, trying a different browser and restarting the notebook server don't help. I also can't find any file in `~/.jupyter` that looks like the culprit.

Comment: Restart the underlying IPython kernel

Comment: @roganjosh I've tried this, no dice

Answer (score 0):

For me only this does the job:

- close the notebook and shutdown its kernel
- close the browser
- close the jupyter process

And then restart everything.

This should be easier!