# Remove play button display at every cell line of Jupyter notebook

Tags: button, jupyter-notebook

I accidentally pressed some buttons on while I was working on Jupyterbook. Now, each cell shows a 'Run this cell (play button)' icon, which is visually distracting. I cannot find a toggle switch/command to turn it off.

Is there anyway I can turn it off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most probably have upgraded the `notebook` package to the version [`5.6.0`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases/tag/5.6.0) or higher.

```
pip show notebook
```

or

```
conda list notebook
```

will get you the exact version you have.

If the above is the case, unfortunately, your options are limited and are as follows.

- **Downgrade**

  ```
  pip install notebook==5.5.0
  ```

  or

  ```
  conda install notebook==5.5.0
  ```
- **Customize local CSS**

  Add the following code (сheck out [this thread](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772) for more flexible and sophisticated solutions) to your `custom.css` file.

  ```
  .code_cell .run_this_cell {
      display: none;
  }
  ```

  If you're using **Conda** on **Linux** you can find the file at (depending on the version of Python you're on)

  ```
  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.css
  ```

  For **Conda** on **Windows** try

  ```
  C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css
  ```

  Check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32156248/4755520) for more details on where the file could be found.

  **Alternatively**, you can create a new file `my-custom.css`, put it anywhere you want and then reference it from every notebook individually by using [IPython's HTML cell magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-html)

  ```
  %%html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="somewhere-on-your-machine/my-custom.css" />
  ```

  or explicitly, without needing to create any files

  ```
  %%html
  <style>
  .code_cell .run_this_cell {
      display: none;
  }
  </style>
  ```

Comment: Please also check out this discussion https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of solving this is to select the cells, change them to markdown and then change back to code.

Comment: Thank you! I was baffled I had to downgrade, change style and so on to revert a typo in my keyboard shortcut. Best solution  IMO