# a black arrow in front of the cell in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I see [an annoying black arrow on my ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTeJ8.jpg) while I using the `python kernel` and 'xeus-cling kernel'.
Please help me understand what is going on with this.

Comment: have you used shift+enter key. what will happen after using this shortcut

Comment: @shubham  I often use this hot key to execute but in this case, nothing will change seemingly...

Comment: @shubham actually , it is good on my pc , but on my iPad , it’s a problem...what a shame

Comment: @shubham the black arrow is still there after the hot key, on my iPad

Comment: I find the same black arrow on my iphone...

Comment: are u running jupyter notebook via anaconda or online

Comment: @shubham I run jupyter on my iPad with anaconda, in the remote way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely due to an upgrade of the notebook package. See this answer for how to downgrade, if you want to get rid of the black icons.

[Remove play button display at every cell line of Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607200/remove-play-button-display-at-every-cell-line-of-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thank you so much and the problem has been solved perfectly. Good idea from you!