# Jupyter config files in sagemath

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

I would like to set a custom stylesheet for my jupyter notebook that I run wtih `sage -n jupyter`.

This command loads the configuration stored in the `.jupyter`-Folder, but I can't find the `ipython profile directory` to put my css files in there. 
Where is this folder located with the default sage installation?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the `iPython` configuration before, but sage now uses `jupyter` now, so the custom css files should be located here.

`~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`

and the js in here:

`~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

i got the answer from [How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

Find the path using `sage -n jupyter --show-config`.

```
sage@3ea4b9627bb1:~$ sage -n jupyter --show-config
Please wait while the Sage Jupyter Notebook server starts...
Loaded config files:
  /home/sage/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.9.9/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

...
```

Comment: This may not show anything, in which case, one might run `sage -n jupyter --generate-config`. [Read more](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)