# How do I increase highlight for selected text of input cells in Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu in Chromium?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, chromium

When I select text of input cells in Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu in Chromium, I can barely see the highlight.  Like this (everything after "100" is highlighted):

[image: weakly highlighted]

On output cells I can easily see the highlighted text (blue background):

[image]

How can I fix this?  It's hard to do copy-paste edits on input cells when I can barely see what I've selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Find your configuration folder (I will assume it is `~/.jupyter`) with

   ```
   import jupyter_core
   jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_config_dir()
   ```

   You can easily find what would be the corresponding directory for Windows, if needed.
2. Create a folder `~/.jupyter/custom`, if it does not exist.
   Other folders might also work ([How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook)).
3. Create an empty file `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`, if it does not exist.
4. Add

   ```
   .cm-s-ipython div.CodeMirror-selected {
       background: #859900 !important;
   }
   ```

   to your `custom.css`.
   Use a suitable color.
5. Reload your notebook in the browser, for immediate results.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by loading jupyter notebook from Terminal (not anaconda), once loaded, I looked for the .css in the execution files that load in the terminal window, and found the styling file.

The file name is style.min.css

```
/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to browse inside the file and your set!

FYI my version of jn:

```
$ jupyter notebook --version
6.0.0
```