# Use external CSS font in Plotly within Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, css, plotly, jupyter, jupyterhub

I would like to use an external font in a Plotly graph made within Jupyter notebook.

From [How do I set custom CSS for my IPython/IHaskell/Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook) I made a cell adding Poppins font whose embed i got from Google Fonts page.

```
%%html
<style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</style>
```

Next using simple Plotly graph as an example I tried to use Poppins font in the next Jupyter code cell

```
# https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=list(range(10)),
    y=[n**2 for n in range(10)]
))
fig.update_layout(
    title="My Plot Title",
    font=dict(
        family="Poppins, monospace", # only this part should matter
        size=20
    )
)
fig.show()
```

The graph is showing monospace, so that means that Poppins font failed to display.

From Chrome Dev tools it seems that %%HTML cell failed to load the font as there is no call to googleapis url.

I am running my own Littlest Jupyter Hub instance so I would consider also making a custom.css