# Jupyter Notebook table design in vs code

Tags: python, datatable, jupyter-notebook

I have a concern working with Jupyter Notebook in VS Code: I was trying to make a simple table using markdown but come across with a simple issue

```
| Class Interval | frequency |
| :------------: | :-------: |
| 10-19 | 3 |
| 20-29 | 5 |
| 30-39 | 3 |
| 40-49 | 1 |
```

I was using this markdown code but the output was not that visually relevant, the headers are really near to each other.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNzpb.png)

How can I fix this? and how can I separate the header to each other visually?

Comment: add some code please.

Comment: that is already the code, I was only using the markdown feature of vs code-jupyter

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting some CSS styling with your table, eg. to style table header elements.

```
<style>
th {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>

| Class Interval | frequency |
| :------------: | :-------:  |
| 10-19 | 3 |
| 20-29 | 5 |
| 30-39 | 3 |
| 40-49 | 1 |
```

While this changed the table in the markdown viewer I was using to test, it doesn't seem to change a Jupyter notebook cell. You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156248/how-do-i-set-custom-css-for-my-ipython-ihaskell-jupyter-notebook#33570738) answer as well.