# HTML: alternate text in a summary-details structure

Tags: html

I just got familiar summary-details structure. For instance, the simple example:

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Which is very cool of course.

Now, is there a way to make the **Details** text switch to, say, **Collapse** once it is pressed and the details are shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with CSS only.

```css
details[open] summary::after {
  content: attr(data-open);
}

details:not([open]) summary::after {
  content: attr(data-close);
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary data-open="Collapse" data-close="Details"></summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Comment: Can I use it within a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Ori5678 You can use it on all devices. CSS is interpreted by the browser. It would be nice if my answer was helpful to accept this answer. If you like it you can upvote , too. And the best would be to get a thank you ;-)

Comment: You're right of course. Manners... Thanks a lot, really. 
Just still not sure how to use that. Usually I'd use


from IPython.display import Markdown as md    then md('<details>...')        

and not sure how to add the CSS part

Comment: @Ori5678 No problem ;-) Thanks for your feedback. What do you mean with: "Just still not sure how to use that"?

Comment: I was in the midst of an edit...

Comment: `from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
</style>
""")` I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570738/14807111

Comment: @Ori5678 You welcome :-)!